# Pass a condition as a function parameter

Tags: r

Is there a way to pass in a  condition as a parameter? For example:

```
#g is some data'

getIndexesWhen <- function (colname, condition) {
    a <- as.vector(g[,colname])
    a <- which(a fits condition)
}
```

And then be able to pass in the condition itself, e.g. call something like `getIndexesWhen('GDP','> 435')`. Or do I need to have separate functions for each case, e.g. =, !=, >, <, etc.?

Comment: You may pass a function (which returns boolean value or boolean vector) as a parameter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of using an expression or function for "greater than 435", you could split up the "greater than" part and the "435" part as arguments to your `getIndexesWhen` function:

```
getIndexesWhen <- function(colname, fxn, rhs) {
  which(fxn(as.vector(g[,colname]), rhs))
}
```

Now you can get the functionality you want without needing to declare a user-defined function for every function/right hand side pairing:

```
g <- iris
getIndexesWhen("Petal.Width", `<`, 0.2)
# [1] 10 13 14 33 38
getIndexesWhen("Petal.Length", `==`, 1.5)
# [1]  4  8 10 11 16 20 22 28 32 33 35 40 49
```

Answer (score 4):

You may pass a function as a parameter:

```
getIndexesWhen<-function(colname, condition)
{
    a<-as.vector(g[,colname])
    return(which(condition(a)))
}

getIndexesWhen("GDP", function(x)x>435)
```

Answer (score 2):

Since you can convert a string to an executable expression using e.g.,:

```
eval(parse(text = "3 > 1"))
```

Or, a string vector of executable expressions using e.g.,:

```
sapply(parse(text = paste0(3:4, "<4")), eval)
```

You could exploit this in your case to pass a *free text condition* by using:

```
getIndexesWhen<-function(g, colname, condition)
{
  a <- as.vector(g[,colname])
  which(sapply(parse(text = paste0(a, condition)), eval))
}
```

This evaluates the column vector against the provided condition.

```
g <- data.frame(C1 = c(2, 3, 4))
getIndexesWhen(g, "C1", ">=3")
```